# How can i save/update a file after changed some text in it?

Tags: c#, winforms

In a SlectedIndexChanged event i'm reading the file content and adding the content to a richTextBox.

```
void listView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ListViewCostumControl.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                results = new List<int>();
                richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(ListViewCostumControl.Items[ListViewCostumControl.SelectedIndices[0]].Text);
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(ListViewCostumControl.Items[ListViewCostumControl.SelectedIndices[0]].Text);
                label17.Text = ExtensionMethods.ToFileSize(fi.Length);
                label17.Visible = true;
                label26.Text = fi.Name;
                label26.Visible = true;
                button5.Enabled = true;
                filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fi.FullName);
                string word = textBox1.Text;
                string[] test = word.Split(new string[] { ",," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                foreach (string myword in test)
                {
                    HighlightPhrase(richTextBox1, myword, Color.Yellow);
                    label16.Text = results.Count.ToString();
                    label16.Visible = true;
                    if (results.Count > 0)
                    {
                        numericUpDown1.Maximum = results.Count;
                        numericUpDown1.Enabled = true;
                        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = results[(int)numericUpDown1.Value - 1];
                        richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Then i'm typing some text inside the richTextBox or deleting text.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (label4.Text == "Viewer")
            {
                richTextBox1.ReadOnly = false;
                button5.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                label4.Text = "Edit";
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
                button6.Enabled = false;
                button5.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                label4.Text = "Viewer";
            }
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            button6.Enabled = true;
        }
```

The problem is once i'm reading and adding the text in the SelectedIndexChanged event to the richTextBox1 it's getting to the richTextBox1_TextChanged event and make button6 enabled true.

But i want it to make button6 enabled true only if i typed/deleted something if i changed something with the text not if the text just added to the richTextBox.

Comment: Please, 1) break your question in two; 2) describe precisely what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Found the solution for this problem. private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (richTextBox1.ReadOnly == false)
                button6.Enabled = true;
        }

Comment: Now i need to find when typing something in the richTextBox1 how to update the file on the hard disk. For example if i read the content of Test.txt to richTextBox1 and then in the richTextBox1 i type something like Hello World and then clicked on button6. So now i want to add the text Hello World to the file Test.txt on the hard disk. Like updating the file on the hard disk.

Comment: *1)* Define a flag at form level to show you are initializing rich text box. *2)* In `SelectedIndexChanged` before loading file content to rich text box, set the flag to true and disable the button and after assigning the file content to rich text box, set initializing to false again. *3)* In the `TextChanged` event of the rich text box, just enable the button if it's not initializing.